# How do I output the image rendered by viewport shading (2.8+)?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I have a scene, and the viewport's render looks fine in my opinion. I don't want to wait very long for a render, so it'd be great if I could output the viewport's shading as a render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the desired 3D Viewport header menu go to *View > Viewport Render Image* ir *Animation* according to what you need.